# Can we rename an existing app on iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

We have live applications on the app store. They're released, active and with a lot of users.

Now, there's talk about renaming one of our apps.

I've never done that personally. Do any of you know if it's possible to update it, and what's the risk?

Answer (score 1):

If the status of your app is Prepare for Submission, you can change your app name. In the past I renamed my apps on the App Store several times, but I'm NOT required a new AppId.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I had to rename an App on the App Store. At that time it was all bad news.  Since the new name required a new AppId all of my existing customers could not receive updates to the program.  And, since it wasn't a subscription model, I had no way to contact them and so was only able to lament this in the product description.  I can only hope that it's better now.